# Jenkins : stderr: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I am hosting Jenkins on a virtual machine(redhat). I am able to setup jenkins system on it and able to access jenkins. But on **manage jenkins** page while creating any build job, when I giv my git repository link, I am getting this error -

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh://git.aaa.aaaa.corp:XXXXX/BSA/myProject.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried to follow many solutions related to SSH keys but of no help.

PLs help.

Comment: I have not configured Jenkins key with my gerrit key. Working now..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Log into your server with the user you installed Jenkins and put your ssh keys under home directory (cd ~). You should have .ssh folder with your public and private keys.
- Go to your Jenkins server : http://JenkinsMaster:Port/**credentials** and press "Add credentials"
- Select SSH Username with private key

  - Scope is Global
  - Username as the user that generated the SSH key
  - Private key from the Jenkins master ~/.ssh
  - Add description such as "service for GIT"
- In your job after selecting GIT as your SCM select those credentials (the field under the repository called credentials)

Good luck!

Comment: Why we need to do this step ?-  Log into your server with the user you installed Jenkins and put your ssh keys under home directory (cd ~). You should have .ssh folder with your public and private keys.

Comment: Depends on the version of Jenkins you have. At the time (2016) at that Jenkins server the only way to put the private key on the master was that way.

Answer (score 8):

When you add new credentials to use jenkins, the private key (.ssh/id_rsa
) should be generate by the user jenkins.

1. sudo -i -u jenkins
2. mkdir ~/.ssh
3. cd ~/.ssh
4. ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "jenkins@git"
5. eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
6. ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
7. cat id_rsa.pub
   Copy the output and add it to your Git repo.
   done

Comment: Just want to stress to people reading this post that the SSH keys **should be generated by the user called "jenkins"** (not the root user or some other user on the system). I made this mistake so don't repeat it!

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the Jenkins server 
Ensure that your user is Jenkins if not run:

```
sudo su jenkins
```

Navigate to /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
Your ssh keys should be here if not or you want to use different ones run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f personalised_key_name -b 4096 -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

Press enter on all questions
To see the newly created keys (personalised_key_name & personalised_key_name.pub) Run:

```
ls
```

To copy the public key to the clipboard run:

```
pbcopy < personalised_key_name.pub
```

Or

```
cat personalised_key_name.pub | pbcopy
```

Go to your remote repository (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket or GitLab ) under your profile or under the repository settings, navigate to SSH Access and paste the public key in your clipboard. Save and go back to Jenkins.
In Jenkins navigate to Credentials > Click on the (global) link > Add credentials

- Kind: SSH Username with private key
- Scope: Global (Jenkins, nodes, items, all child items, etc)
- ID: Give it your chosen credential id e.g Git_Jenkinkis_CI
- Private key: Your private key from Jenkins (personalised_key_name)
- Passphrase:Optional passphrase.

Go to you job and configure it.
Paste your correct **ssh** repository URL under "Source Code Management"
Under Credentials select the Jenkins credentials you just created and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I have not configured Jenkins key with my gerrit key. Working now..