# Jenkins: stderr: Permission denied (publickey) error not resolving

Tags: jenkins, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have setup SSH key on `CENTOS 7` server and also have `added SSH` in my `Bitbucket` personal settings. But still I am getting Jenkins error as:

[image]

Although I have setup ssh key on `CENTOS 7` server where the Jenkins is installed. On running `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` command in terminal I am getting a number of lines and it seems that the connection has been established successfully. The terminal output was:

[image]

But still I am getting authentication error.

I have tried other solutions like [Jenkins Shared Library: Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318766/jenkins-shared-library-permission-denied-publickey) and [Jenkins : stderr: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432519/jenkins-stderr-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-u) But none of them worked. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `Repository URL` is not correct. If you have setup `SSH` connection in bitbucket then you should use url accordingly.

- Go to Bitbucket and click on `clone` button ion your repository.
- Select `SSH` on the top right of the dialogue being displayed.
- Copy the url written after `git clone` keyword. It will go like
  `git@.....`
  That should work.